# Oz's Personality in "Oz the Great and Powerful"

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, character, oz-the-great-and-powerful

In the first part of the movie, [*Oz: The Great and Powerful*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_the_Great_and_Powerful), Oz's personality with his assistant was kinda mean, he even said to his assistant that "You're just a trained monkey." Also he said "You're not my friend".

We also noticed about deceiving women with his "Grandmother's Music Box".

Then during a Tornado/Whirlwind he was about to die but shouted "I'm Going to change, I promise etc....."

Then when he arrived in the land of Oz he still had the same mean attitude with the monkey and in deceiving women with the witches.

My question is: Did Oz actually change? (except for the greed of gold). I thought the movie was also pointing out about Changing his attitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I believe Oz did change. This is most evident through the final scene in which he begins the tradition of presenting gifts to others.

To Finley (the monkey), Oz says:

> You stood by me when other monkeys would have flown away.

He then declares him a friend of Oz. To me, this is a sincere appreciation of Finley's companionship and a positive personality shift.

Furthermore, using his deceitfulness and sleight of hand techniques to thwart the witches provides a realization for Oz that his talents can be used for the good of others, an endeavor that it is implied he intends to pursue.

Comment: yeah! now I remember, He also gave his own prized possessions as a sign of respect and gratitude, like his `Hat` and `all-purpose-knife-spoon-fork` HAHA, and The Queen also said its not Greatness but Goodness :D tnx colti